# Jar inclusion Issue

Tags: jar

How can i add external jars to my project before exporting the project so that the person about to use my code need not have to download those jars.He simply has to refer the jar i provided to run my project(Not using Maven).
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to create a zip file containing 
your_jar.jar
the libraries needed in a subdirectory lib
and add a manifest-classpath entry to point to those libraries

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Hand
Main-Class: com.bitplan.gen.parser.m2java
Class-Path: lib/com.bitplan.smartgenerator-4.2.3.jar
```

After unzipping your code can be started with java -jar your_jar.jar